# Why not moderate questions from new users before making them visible on site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions, review, new-users

I had suggested before also that questions from new users should not be posted directly on the site rather they should be moderated first and they should be visible to only users with high reputation (say 600 rep) so that **duplicate posts, rants and spam like posts** could be controlled. And once the user has atleast 10 reputation or **he/she has asked two questions** *which are not a duplicate and are not a spam*, this moderation for posting his/her questions on site should be removed.

This would make Ask Ubuntu clean.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185530/270345

Comment: I'm pretty sure one of Atwood or Spolsky specifically mentioned this as something they wouldn't do in Stack Exchange. Can't find the post now. And it doesn't happen at [so], so it's doubtful it will fallen here.

Comment: It would only add one more thing to review. As it is now, spam is flagged and managed rapidly. New users are moderated / moderated in several ways already in ways you can access depending on your reputation see http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges.  In addition, IMO it is unwelcoming when as a new user you can not post questions. The overwhelming majority of new users are legitimate and so I subscribe to "if it not broken don't fix it".

Comment: With > 500 rep you can help with these things - http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues

Answer (score 4):

It's always difficult to find the [yellow brick road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_brick_road) when dealing with any group of humans!  **;-)**

Most users are decent and nearly all *mean well*. <sub>You're such an example as otherwise you wouldn't be asking this question...</sub>

The system is not perfect, but most users understand that by the time they have 20 rep that this site is a bit different from the traditional forum and by the time they hit 10000 rep they are still learning and still get corrected...  (Well, dumbasses like me still get corrected)  **>:)**

It can sometimes be a drag if you see *[yet another low quality post](https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts)* but that's why this was set up that way...  Don't just edit their answer, but leave a comment that they should review your edits, tell them to visit the [Ask Ubuntu Tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) to better understand how this site works, have them review the [editing help](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of their questions and, basically, help advance the human race towards more open and free software!

## :-)